# A/libc Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xd2044d4c (code=1), thread 5786 (FinalizerDaemon) error when setPreviewCallback is called

Tags: android, c, camera, video-streaming, native

I have this peculiar issue where my app crashes with SIGSEGV error in my camera module occasionally. Using the Camera.PreviewCallback implementation the **onPreviewFrame** method does gets called around **8-10** times,before getting crashed with log trace as below :

```
07-22 12:37:34.981    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp V/surfaceChanged﹕ entered
07-22 12:37:37.834    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp V/surfaceChanged﹕ entered

07-22 12:37:40.056    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-22 12:37:40.056    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-22 12:37:40.056    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 64
07-22 12:37:40.056    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 64
07-22 12:37:40.126    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp E/MainActivity﹕ onPreviewFrame
07-22 12:37:40.227    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp E/MainActivity﹕ onPreviewFrame
07-22 12:37:40.387    5777-6254/com.example.surveyapp D/dalvikvm﹕ **GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4059K, 28% free 12685K/17596K, paused 37ms, total 37ms**
07-22 12:37:40.387    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp E/MainActivity﹕ onPreviewFrame
07-22 12:37:40.467    5777-5777/com.example.surveyapp E/MainActivity﹕ onPreviewFrame
07-22 12:37:40.647    5777-5788/com.example.surveyapp D/dalvikvm﹕ **GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1364K, 31% free 12223K/17596K, paused 53ms, total 53ms**
07-22 12:37:40.647    5777-5786/com.example.surveyapp A/libc﹕ **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xd2044d4c (code=1), thread 5786 (FinalizerDaemon)**
```

This behaviour does not occur all the time,but whenever I login from my app and go into this Camera Module ,this error occurs.If I directly enter camera module from my DashBoard page this error does not occurs or If i run this camera module as standalone application no error occurs.

**Note :** I am also using native C code for encryption purpose in this app

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @user2106108 I'm seeing this as well (calling into the c lib) and crashing after a GC event.